# Library or framework for authentication of web clients

Tags: web-services, user-management, authentication

I am looking for a framework that I can use to build an authentication server, and can also store other information into the database with. I am looking to use this as a single service to authenticate, create accounts, and manage the data for a project and their respective applications across platforms. Basically act as a middle man between the main desktop application and the client applications(android, ios, etc.)

A couple of years back I rolled my own using C# and a asp.net authentication provider- which I might still use but I am trying to get away from the .net ecosystem on this project. I figured there must be quite a few tools for the job here, and I am wondering what the popular frameworks for this are. I was thinking about rolling my own in node or go, but I wan't to see what implementations exist already.

I should add that I am not looking for an oath2 framework. I would like to manage my user information on my own servers. Language isn't very important, just looking for something with an ecosystem.